# PHP Blank page but every other page works

Tags: php

Here's the error I'm getting in my error log

```
[Wed Mar 12 15:54:04.809152 2014] [:error] [pid 6111] [client] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) in /home/toolplas/public_html/main/new_incoming.php on line 354, referer: https://toolplas.com/post_file.php?job_num=1000
```

Its weird because this exact page works on my dev server.

Code:

```
<?php
$page = 'New Incoming Data';
$renamed = false;
$post_array = array('folder' => null);
require_once('includes/config.php');
require_once('includes/auth.php');
if($loggedin) {
require_once('includes/header.php');

if(isset($_SESSION['new'])){
   $post_json = $_SESSION['post'];
   $new_json = $_SESSION['new'];
   unset($_SESSION['post']);
   unset($_SESSION['new']);
   $post_array = jsonDecode($post_json);
   $new_files_array = json_decode($new_json);
   if($debug){
      echo '<div style="margin-left:201px"><pre>';
         print_r($new_files_array);
      echo '</pre></div>';
      echo '<div style="margin-left:201px"><pre>';
         print_r($post_array);
      echo '</pre></div>';
   }
   $renamed = true;
   $url = stripcslashes($post_array['url']);
   require_once('/home/toolplas/public_html/Twig/Autoloader.php');

   Twig_Autoloader::register();
   $loader = new Twig_Loader_String();
   $twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
}

?>
<script type='text/javascript'>
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#folder').html('');
      $('#folder').append('<option>Select</option>');
      $.ajax({
         url: 'phplib/list_folder.php',
         type: 'post',
         data: { date: $('#date').val()<?php

            /*if($renamed){
               echo ", current: '" . $post_array['folder'] . "'";
            }*/

            ?> },
         dataType: 'json',
         success: function(data){
            $.each(data, function(){
               if(this === '<?php echo $post_array['folder'] ?>'){
                  $('#folder').append('<option selected="selected" value="' + this + '">' + this + '</option>');
               } else {
                  $('#folder').append('<option value="' + this + '">' + this + '</option>');
               }
            })
         }
      });
      var parts = [ <?php echo getparts($dbc3); ?> ];
      //$('.part_input').autocomplete({ source: "phplib/json_search.php?table=indata_part_type&field=name" });
      $('#program').autocomplete({ source: "phplib/json_search.php?table=view_program&field=program" });
      $('#contact').autocomplete({ source: "phplib/json_search.php?table=indata_contacts&field=name" });
      $('#source').autocomplete({ source: "phplib/json_search.php?table=data_source&field=name" });
      $('#date').change(function(){
         $('#folder').html('');
         $('#folder').append('<option>Select</option>');
         $.ajax({
            url: 'phplib/list_folder.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {
               date: $(this).val()
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
               $.each(data, function(){
                  $('#folder').append('<option value="' + this + '">' + this + '</option>');
               })
            }
         });
      });
      $('#fetch').click(function(){
          $.ajax({
            url: "phplib/get_infiles2.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                cust: $('#source').val(),
                date: $('#date').val(),
                folder: $('#folder').val(),
                intype: $('[name^=in_type]').serializeArray(),
                outtype: $('[name^=out_type]').serializeArray()
            },
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(data){
                $('#files').html(data);
            }
        });
      });
      $('.add_type').live('click',function(){
         $html = $(this).parent().html();
         $(this).parent().parent().append('<p>' + $html + '</p>');
      });
      /*$('#add_fease').live('click',function(){
         $.ajax({
            url: 'phplib/get_feases.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {
               job_num: $('[name^=file]')
            },
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(data){
               alert(data);
            }
         });
      });*/
      $('form').validate();
   });
</script>
<div id="content">
   <h2>New Incoming Data</h2>
   <form action='phplib/new_incoming.php' method='post'>
   <div id='indata'>
      <div id='formhead'>

         <div id='left' style='width:400px;'>
            <p>
               <label>Autogenerated Q Number</label>
               <input name='q_num' value="<?php if($renamed) echo $post_array['q_num']; else echo getnextqnum($dbc3); ?>" />
            </p>
            <p>
               <label>Data Source</label>
               <input name='source' id='source' value="<?php if($renamed) echo $post_array['source']; ?>" />
            </p>
            <p>
               <label>Date Received</label>
               <input name='date' id='date' class='datepicker' value="<?php if($renamed) echo $post_array['date']; else echo date(INPUT_DATE_FMT, strtotime('NOW')) ?>" />
            </p>
            <p>
               <label>Media</label>
               <select name='media' required>
                  <option value=''>Select</option>
                  <?php
                      $sql = "SELECT * FROM media";
                      $result = mysqli_query($dbc3, $sql);
                      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                          echo "<option";
                         if($renamed) if($post_array['media'] == $row['id']) echo " selected='selected'";
                          echo " value='" . $row['id'] . "'>" . $row['name'] . "</option>";
                      }
                  ?>
               </select>
            </p>
            <p>
               <label>Program</label>
               <input name='program' id='program' value="<?php if($renamed) echo $post_array['program']; ?>" />
            </p>
            <p>
               <label>Contact</label>

               <input name='contact' id='contact' value="<?php if($renamed) echo $post_array['contact']; ?>" />
            </p>
            <p>
               <label>Filename/PKG</label>
                    <?php if($renamed){
                  echo "<input type='text' name='folder' id='folder' readonly='readonly' value='" . $post_array['folder'] . "' />";
               } else { ?>
               <select name='folder' id='folder'>
                  <option>Select</option>
               </select>
                    <? } ?>
            </p>
         </div>
         <div id='right' style='margin-left:400px;'>
            <?php if($renamed){
               $in_type = $post_array['in_type'];
               $out_type = $post_array['out_type'];

               $intype = array();
               foreach($in_type as $key => $value){
                  $intype[] = $value['value'];
               }
               $outtype = array();
               foreach($out_type as $key => $value){
                  $outtype[] = $value['value'];
               }

               foreach($intype as $key => $value){
               ?>

               <p>
                  <label>In Type</label>
                  <select name='in_type[]'>

                     <?php
                         $sql = "SELECT * FROM datatype";
                         $result = mysqli_query($dbc3, $sql);
                         while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                           echo "<option";
                             if($renamed) if($value == $row['id']) echo " selected='selected'";
                             echo " value='" . $row['id'] . "'>" . $row['name'] . "</option>";
                         }
                     ?>
                  </select>
                  <label>Out Type</label>
                  <select name='out_type[]'>

                     <?php
                         $sql = "SELECT * FROM datatype";
                         $result = mysqli_query($dbc3, $sql);
                         while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                           echo "<option";
                             if($renamed){ if($outtype[$key] == $row['id']) echo " selected='selected'"; }
                             else{ if($row['name'] == 'Iges') echo " selected='selected'"; }
                             echo " value='" . $row['id'] . "'>" . $row['name'] . "</option>";
                         }
                     ?>
                  </select>
                  <a href='javascript:void()' class='add_type'>Add</a>
               </p>

               <?php }
            } else { ?><p>
               <label>In Type</label>
               <select name='in_type[]'>

                  <?php
                      $sql = "SELECT * FROM datatype";
                      $result = mysqli_query($dbc3, $sql);
                      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                        echo "<option";
                          if($renamed) if($post_array['data_type'] == $row['id']) echo " selected='selected'";
                          echo " value='" . $row['id'] . "'>" . $row['name'] . "</option>";
                      }
                  ?>
               </select>
               <label>Out Type</label>
               <select name='out_type[]'>

                  <?php
                      $sql = "SELECT * FROM datatype";
                      $result = mysqli_query($dbc3, $sql);
                      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                        echo "<option";
                          if($renamed){ if($post_array['data_type'] == $row['id']) echo " selected='selected'"; }
                          else{ if($row['name'] == 'Iges') echo " selected='selected'"; }
                          echo " value='" . $row['id'] . "'>" . $row['name'] . "</option>";
                      }
                  ?>
               </select>
               <a href='javascript:void()' class='add_type'>Add</a>
            </p>
            <?php } ?>

         </div>
         <div style='clear:both'></div>
         <input type='button' id='fetch' value='Fetch All The Things' />
      </div>
      <div id='files'>
      <?php if($renamed){ ?>
      <h2>Files</h2>
      <?php
         $indatatype = array();
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM datatype_extension";
   $result = mysqli_query($dbc3, $sql);
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
      if(in_array($row['datatype'], $intype)){
          $indatatype[] = $row['ext'];
      }
   }

   $datatype = array();
   foreach($in_type as $key => $value){
      $datatype[] = array('in' => $value['value'], 'out' => $out_type[$key]['value']);
   }
   //print_r($datatype);
   //echo $url;
   $files = array();
   if ($handle = opendir($url)) {
      $num = 0;
      while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
         if ($file != '.' && $file != '..' && $file != 'Thumbs.db' && !is_dir("$url/$file")){
            if(in_array(strtolower(pathinfo("$url/$file", PATHINFO_EXTENSION)), $indatatype)){
               foreach($intype as $key => $value){
                  if(getfileext($value) == strtolower(pathinfo("$url/$file", PATHINFO_EXTENSION))){
                     $in = $value;
                     $out = $outtype[$key];
                  }
               }
               $files[] = array('o_name' => $file, 'outtype' => $out, 'intype' => $in, 'size' => number_format(filesize("$url/$file")));
            }
         }
      }
   }

   $part_type = array();
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM indata_part_type";
   $result = mysqli_query($dbc3, $sql);
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
       $part_type[] = array('name' => $row['name'], 'id' => $row['id']);
   }

$html = <<<EOF
   <table class='fancy'>
      <thead>
         <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Job Number</th>
            <th>New File Name</th>
            <th>Original File Name</th>
            <th>File Size</th>
            <th>Part</th>
            <th>Part Number</th>
            <th>Description</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         {% for item in files %}
            <tr>
               <td style='text-align:center;'><input type='checkbox' name="file[{{ loop.index }}][active]" value='YES' checked='checked' style='width:20px;'  /></td>
               <td><input style='width:100%;' name="file[{{ loop.index }}][job_num]" value='{{ item.job_num }}' /></td>
               <td><input style='width:100%;' class='unique' name="file[{{ loop.index }}][n_file]" value='{{ item.n_file }}' /></td>
               <td>{{ item.o_file }}<input type='hidden' name="file[{{ loop.index }}][o_file]" readonly='readonly' value='{{ item.o_file }}' /></td>
               <td>{{ item.size }}<input type='hidden' name="file[{{ loop.index }}][size]" readonly='readonly' value='{{ item.size }}' /></td>
               <td><select name="file[{{ loop.index }}][part]">
                  <option value=''>Select</option>
                  {% for part in parts %}
                  <option value='{{ part.id }}'{% if item.part == part.id %} selected='selected'{% endif %}>{{ part.name }}</option>
                  {% endfor %}
               </select></td>
               <td><input style='width:100%;' name="file[{{ loop.index }}][part_num]" value='{{ item.part_num }}' /></td>
               <td><input style='width:100%;' name="file[{{ loop.index }}][desc]" value='{{ item.desc }}' /></td>
               <input type='hidden' name='file[{{ loop.index }}][outext]' value='{{ item.outext }}' />
               <input type='hidden' name='file[{{ loop.index }}][inext]' value='{{ item.inext }}' />
               <input type='hidden' name='file[{{ loop.index }}][version]' value='{{ item.version }}' />
            </tr>
         {% endfor %}
      </tbody>
   </table>
   <input type='hidden' name='url' value='{{ url }}' /><input type='submit' name='rename' value='Rename' /> <input type='submit' name='add_fease' id='add_fease' value='Add Fease' /> <input type='submit' name='submit' id='submit' value='Submit' />
EOF;

   echo $twig->render( $html, array('files' => $new_files_array, 'parts' => $part_type, 'url' => $url) );

       } ?>
      </div>

   </div>
   </form>
</div>
<?php
  require_once('includes/footer.php');
  } else echo showlogin();
?>
```

Sorry its pretty long. The Else its complaining about is at the very end of the file. Anyone have a clue ?

Comment: Looks like you have an else without an if, just like the error says.

Comment: are errors turned off on your dev server?

Comment: @RUJordan According to NP++'s bracket highlighter it *should* be matching `if($loggedin) {` on line 7.

Comment: @RUJordan There is an if at the very top. Hard to say if it's a matching if.

Comment: You gave us code that doesn't have the line 357 that is mentioned in the error. Can you give us the most recent file it refers to?

Comment: you should really start using curly brackets. Much easier to read and debug

Comment: @pthurmond sorry about that I had error reporting code at the top and took it out when copying the code over here.

Edited post with new error from error log.

Comment: You should consistently use curly braces for the contents of all conditionals. In fact I highly recommend following php-fig standards as much as possible. Especially PSR-1 and PSR-2 (http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/).

Comment: @Ronnie Curly brackets ? You mean curly braces?

Comment: @pthurmond I didn't write this. But how come it works on my dev server but not production?

Comment: Even when I copy the contents and paste them onto the dev server the file still runs fine.. I'm puzzled.

Comment: @MikeOscarEcho - If it works on your dev server and not in production, there is something different in the environment causing it. Find the difference.

Comment: @MikeOscarEcho What PHP versions do you run on the servers?

Comment: @h2ooooooo I just checked and on the dev Version 5.4.25 and on the production version 5.5.9. Could this be the reason why ? I tried downgrading the production (I upgraded it earlier today accidentally) and I thought it did it but I guess not.

Comment: I can confirm that my PHP parser thinks the file is in error -- I ran `php -l` on it and got the same error about the unexpected 'else'.

Comment: time to start deleting blocks of code till it no longer errors. hunt it down the hard way

Comment: How do you accidentally upgrade a production server?

Comment: @JohnP Easy. When you put an inexperienced person at the helm they tend to make mistakes.

Comment: @MikeOscarEcho - Ok, I can buy that. We've had a few experiences like that :)

Comment: @MikeOscarEcho yes braces..brackets, braces, whatever lol..the only curly ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is on line 170:

```
                <? } ?>
```

Note that you've got a [short open tag](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php) there: `<?` rather than `<?php`. I can reproduce your parse error and eliminate it by replacing the open tag with a full `<?php` open tag.

I'd therefore deduce that your production server doesn't have `short_open_tag` turned on.  You should make sure `short_open_tag` is disabled on your development server if you're going to have it disabled on production.

I'd also recommend looking into more structured PHP development practices -- probably by checking out a few of the top frameworks that are around -- to see if you get some hints as to how to reduce the complexity of this code. The intermingling of PHP, HTML, jQuery, Mustache, and styling attributes that might be better handled with CSS, all in the one big file, seems quite unwieldy to be dealing with.

Comment: Thanks for spotting that! And I agree wholeheartedly about your 3rd paragraph. The previous dev actually started re-writing part of the application using Silex but I've yet to delve into it and start learning it. Eventually the entire app will be using that framework because right now its a complete mess.